# Delete message from inbox

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I have deleted some post but it still shows the comment of the deleted post in my inbox. How to delete those message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply can't. They'll be marked as read once you click the StackExchange notification and will remain there. It's was once a valid notification, and remains a notification to this day.